# How to move files stored in a directory and its subdirectories to a different directory?

Tags: python

I have a ton of images stored in many subdirectories that need to be moved to a single directory. Many of these files have the exact same name, even though they may be present in different subdirectories.

I have tried this, and it works perfectly. However, it is not able to access the files stores in subdirectories. What changes can I make so that it moves the files from subdirectories as well.

```
import os
import shutil
import datetime
import glob

now = str(datetime.datetime.now())
now = now.replace(":","")
count = 1

dirr = 'path'
move = '/path_to_directory_where_the_files_are_to_be_moved'
for files in os.listdir(dirr): 
    if files.endswith('20.jpg') or files.endswith('29.jpg'):
        src = dirr + files
        dst = move + files+str(now)+'.jpg'
        shutil.copy(src, dst)
        print("copied " + str(count) +' files \n')
        count +=1
```

I finally got it working, and I have shared the final code below.

import os
import shutil
import datetime
import glob
import time
count = 1

```
dirr = 'path'
move = '/path_to_directory_where_the_files_are_to_be_moved'

for files in glob.glob(dirr + '/**', recursive=True):
    if files.endswith('20.jpg') or files.endswith('29.jpg'):
        now = str(datetime.datetime.now())
        now = now.replace(":","")
        print(files)
        files1 = os.path.basename(files)
        src = dirr + files1
        dst = move + files1+str(now)+'.jpg'
        #print(src, dst)
        shutil.copy(files, dst)
        #time.sleep(0.05) ## use only when you want to make absolutely sure that each file gets a unique name when it is being copied. You won't need it anyway, but just in case
        print("copied " + str(count) +' files \n')
        count +=1
```

Comment: Did you look into [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)?

Comment: Yes, I tired os.walk(). But, it gives me an error with files.endswith(). So, I can't use it.

Comment: What error do you get with files.endswith()?

Comment: @mrzo It says AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'endswith'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have already imported glob, let's put it to use, the for loop here is a replacement of the for loop you are using but it gets all the files in the subdirectories:

```
import os
import shutil
import datetime
import glob

now = str(datetime.datetime.now())
now = now.replace(":","")
count = 1

dirr = 'path'
move = '/path_to_directory_where_the_files_are_to_be_moved'

for files in glob.iglob('path' + '**/**', recursive=True):
    files = os.path.basename(files)  # This is to get the file name without the directory name attached to it
    if files.endswith('20.jpg') or files.endswith('29.jpg'):
        src = dirr + files
        dst = move + files+str(now)+'.jpg'
        shutil.copy(src, dst)
        print("copied " + str(count) +' files \n')
        count +=1
```

Comment: shutil.copy() rasises FileNotFound error. Otherwise, it seems to read files within the subdirectoties.
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'path/xxx_20.jpg'

Comment: Thank You. It needed a few minor changes, and it worked perfectly. I have shared the final code in the edits in case anyone needs it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `walk` ([Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk))

```
import os


def file_filter(filename: str) -> bool:
    ...


def copy_file(filename: str, src_folder: str, dst_folder: str):
    ...


src = 'path'
dst = 'dst_path'

i = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src):
    for f in filter(file_filter, files):
        copy_file(f, root, dst)
        i += 1
```